# Accidentally deleted my /etc directory, now unable to SSH into my VPS

Tags: ssh

After installing and then removing a package on my Ubuntu 17.04 VPS through the apt remove command, somehow my /etc directory got deleted.

My VPS is still running, however, I'm unable to SSH into it.

I was wondering whether it's possible to restore SSH access or access the disk and retrieve the files that away.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is broken.  You'll only be able to access it is if your VPS provider provides an out-of-band method to access it such as a virtual console - many VPS providers do provide this.

However in this case it's not likely to even meaningfully boot or do much without `/etc`, so you'll probably need to restore from a recent snapshot (easiest) or if you don't have a snapshot, you'll have to do a fresh image and then start restoring what you need from whatever backup you have.